# How to use tf.map_fn to iterate over a tensor and return values of different dimensions for each iteration?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wanted to iterate over a tensor without using Eager Execution for which I had to use tf.map_fn().
What I want to do can be shown as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

list_of_values = tf.constant([[1, 9, 65, 43], [8, 23, 21, 48], [11, 14, 98, 21], [98, 12, 32, 12]])

def value_finder(i):
  def f1():
    # Some computation with a local variable 'a' occurs
    # . . .
    return a  # a = [[3, 4, 5]]

  def f2():
    # Some computation with a local variable 'b' occurs
    # . . .
    return b  # b = [[7, 1, 2], [9, 3, 11]]

  return tf.cond(tf.reduce_all(tf.less(tf.slice(i, [1], [1]), tf.constant(18))), f1, f2)

value_obtained = tf.map_fn(lambda i: value_finder(i), list_of_values))
```

The values a and b are not of the same dimension hence I get an error whenever I try to run my code. In my case, it is inevitable for the values that get returned to be of uneven dimension. Is there any way other way to iterate the tensor and get results other than to pad the values to make them of equal dimensions?

Comment: Maybe you can consider using [`Ragged Tensors`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors) to support variable length tensor.